# what should I use to animate a character?

Tags: android, ios

I want to make app (something like a book with animations), where will be a character that will be able to perform simple movements like:

1. Walking back and forth(left and right).
2. Pseudo 3D - character can go
   up to the screen and move away from it.
3. Сharacter can handle some
   sort of object and perform any action with it.
4. Character can turn around himself.
5. It should be very nice looking.

All movements are known in advance, it is not a game.
The rest part of the application I want to make in the native SDK (android and iOS). The question is what should I use to reach the objectives.
The best way for me (I think, maybe you think different) is using crossplatform game engine, but I cant figure out what engine good for this purpose. Unity 3d looks too complicated for this. Marmalade - as I know - there is no way to use it with native sdk. Can I use for this purposes cocos2d-x?

I'm totally new in game development and I would not want to spend a lot of time to study what would be useless.

Comment: check out http://www.cocos2d-x.org One of the best open source, cross-platform game engines out there. Its well documented too.

Comment: I already checked it out, looks good, but I want to know whether this is the best way or not.

Comment: when it comes to cross-platform integration, I'd say its one of da easiest and efficient ways of doing it. It uses C++ and is easy to understand. I'd recommend that. I've built couple of iOS using Cocos2D (the Obj-C) version of Cocos2D-x. Its good and simple

Comment: Can I make with it 2 and 4 points?

Comment: what do you mean 2 and 4 points? didnt get you

Comment: sorry for my english, I mean second and fourth items of my list.

Comment: you can do that with Cocos2d-x. You can use multiple sprites (images sorts) and create 3D. Or you can try out Cocos3D but I think its not cross-platform, only Obj-C.

Answer (score 0):

a cross platform way is plain opengl or a 3d engine:

- cocos2d which is quite popular .
- unity3D which is also nice IMO

plain opengl is cumbersome and often not productive so I'd go with an engine

Answer (score 0):

1. Cocos2D-x
2. SIO2 it pretty nice too http://sio2interactive.com/
3. Unity3D (30 day evaluation)
4. Shiva3D

Check [this link out](http://webification.com/best-iosandroid-cross-platform-mobile-development-sdks) . Gives you a detailed comparison.